# Selenium try/catch click seems to take a long time?

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I always have an issue when writing Selenium tests where trying to issue a click on an element that's not ready can result in a StaleElementReference/ElementClickIntercepted exception. This was able to make tests flaky by making tests fail where they succeed if I just wait 2 seconds for an item to be clickable.

I already had a fix for `WebElement` retrieval where I use implicit waits to wait for an element's appearance for about 2 seconds before I deem it missing, and I've been trying to create a `clickElement()` function that surrounds the basic `click()` function to fulfill the same purpose.

Its purpose is to keep trying to click in 100ms increments until it can. I do this by catching exceptions and incrementing a counter for every click and only break out of the loop when either the element is clicked or too many attempts to click have raised exceptions.

This is the function I wrote:

```java
public void clickElement(WebElement element) {
    int maxTimeOut = 50;
    int timeOutCt = 0;
    boolean isTimedOut = false;
    System.out.println("=> Try to click on <" + element.getTagName() + ">");
    while ( !isTimedOut ) {
        try {
            element.click();
            isTimedOut = true; // could click
            System.out.println("\n OK \n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            waitSeconds(0.1);
            timeOutCt++;
            System.out.println(" \t => Error while attempting to click for the " + timeOutCt +"nd time \n");
            if ( timeOutCt > maxTimeOut ) { 
                isTimedOut = true;
                fail("Element <" + element.getTagName() + "> is not clickable. See exception:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

waitSeconds is:

```
public void waitSeconds(double t) {
    long mT = (long) (t * 1000);
    try {
        System.out.print("\n \t \t ( ) Sleep de " + mT + "secondes"); 
        Thread.sleep(mT);
        System.out.print(" ... Done \n ");
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that doing this seems to take an absurdly long time, longer than a millisecond at the very least, at the very least I can say that it lasts more than a second.
I thought maybe my `waitSeconds()` function didn't work properly but I tested it in a simple program and it works as it should: `waitSeconds(0.1)` results in a 100ms wait.

So why is it that when `clickElement` is called and it tries to click on an element multiple times, it can take up to two seconds between two attempts?

Is it the console outputs that are slowing it down?

Or is it the try/catch that's messing everything up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced somewhat similar issue for try/catch, Try disabling the implicit wait before the try/catch block and enabling it again after catch.Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

> Suggestion

1. If you are using implicit wait at the beginning, please remove it and use explicit wait whenever you want to wait.
2. Use if condition before you trying to perform click i.e if the element is visible then only click on the element
3. Use the **break** keyword after you perform to click

Please try this, hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: This isn't really feasible in my case as I would have to go back through a large amount of tests to add explicit waits where necessary.

Comment: If explicit wait doesn't work for you. You can use fluent wait. I don't suggest anyone use implicit wait in the script. @Grumbunks